# Video Decoding using VA-API

Tags: ffmpeg, hardware-acceleration

I've been trying to implement video acceleration in libavg using VA-API video decoding with ffmpeg. They already have the VDPAU support for it. From their source code I understood that it has to do something with struct *vaapi_context and some functions - get_format, get_buffer, release_buffer - but I can't figure how to make that work.

It would be great if someone would be so nice to share simple notes how to set up and use functions to get avcodec_decode_video done with vaapi.

Comment: If they already do it in their source, what more do you need? Look at their source and see how they do it.

Comment: I have checked their source code as well as xbmc source code. By looking into that I think vaapi and vdpau implementation is different. Also, I am not a c++ developer so I do't understand at all what to do?

Comment: If you're not a C++ developer, what language do you use - C#, python, VB.NET? I think there are bindings of ffmpeg for various languages.

Comment: I am a c# python developer, but my problem is that I am using python to play my video using libavg multimedia framework and libavg is developed using C++, so if I want to change its working then I will have to use C++ only.

Comment: So basically, you are trying to change the code of libavg?

Comment: yes I want to implement VA-API support in libavg so that my python player will be able to play video smoothly using libavg

Comment: I would advice you to start learning C++ then. There's no other way you could do it.